# Ajax get a return value from php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to alert the return value from a php method, but nothing happens. Here is the ajax and php methods. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

--------------------------------------…
Ajax script

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/donation/junk/4',
    data: datastring,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data');
    }
});
```

--------------------------------------…
php method

```
function junk($id)
{
    return "works11";
}
```

Comment: Your JS has a syntax error.

Comment: You would need to call the method in the PHP file for it to return the data. Example... echo junk(4); ... somewhere in the php file

Answer (score 37, accepted):

in PHP, you can't simply return your value and have it show up in the ajax response. you need to `print` or `echo` your final values. (there are other ways too, but that's getting off topic).

also, you have a trailing apostrophe in your `alert()` call that will cause an error and should be removed.

Fixed:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/donation/junk/4',
    data: datastring,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
function junk($id)
{
    print "works11";
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about... you can alert the return from an ajax call all you want.

Comment: no no no. you can't return TO an ajax call from PHP without printing or echoing.

Comment: I see what you are saying... the PHP needs to echo something... or exit(status), etc...

Comment: @zgr024 now you've got it.

Comment: but you still need to call the method... your still just defining it

Comment: Thank you for the help. I really need to be able to return a value back to the ajax method so I can update a field on the form. Do you have any examples or places on the net I could see some examples? Thanks a ton

Comment: simple, after you printed it, return it.

Comment: you make it :) I use echo to return the value. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra ' in there on the alert(data') line

This should work

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/donation/junk/4',
    data: datastring,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

And your PHP code should call the method also and echo the value

```
function junk($id) {
    return 'works11';
}
exit(junk(4));
```

All you're doing currently is creating the method

Answer (score -1):

ajax returns text, it does not communicate with php via methods.  It requests a php page and the return of the ajax request is whatever the we babe would have showed if opened in a browser.