# Ajax Get results from sql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm fairly new to web development and php.

I have a js file with all my functions. In one of the functions I make an ajax call to create a new database record that person A is making a challenge to person B.

**JS**

```
var challengeeId = document.getElementById('Challengee').value;

$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url: baseUrl+"/site/challenge",
    data:{"challengeeId":challengeeId},
    cache:false,
    success: function(html){
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$model = new Challenge();
$model->challenger_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
$model->challengee_id = $_POST['challengeeId'];
$model->date_created = date("Y-d-m H:i:s");
$model->status ="pending";
$model->save();
```

This is fine and saves in table correctly. The table also creates an id for every challenge.  I want to know how to return that id so that I can store it as a variable in my JS file for later use. I have an SQL query which returns the ID for me, I just don't know how to return it from the PHP to JS.

Comment: You can echo or print your result, in this case the id. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15126627/3558900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sure you get the last id

If using postgresql

```
$lastID = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID('table_sequence');
return $lastID;
```

If using mysql

```
$lastID = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
return $lastID;
```

since getLastInsertID is accessor method you also call like this too

```
$lastID = Yii::app()->db->lastInsertID;
return $lastID;
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is super useful to me. I can definitely use this.

Comment: @AlecGamble Most Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to return that value back either as a string or maybe a json return and then that becomes the "html" var in your "success" case of the ajax call. You then handle the rest in javascript

Comment: Thank you very much, that's useful to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You could echo the id in php. the variabele html will then contain the id.